# how to find a particular key in output of python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python function `rows` which output as:

```
(
 [u'ABC'],
 [u'DEF'], 
 [u'GHI']
)
```

I want to search `DEF` in this and `print("Hello")`

I did this:

```
for i in rows[]:
    if i == "DEF":
        print("Hello")
```

But this is not working. Can someone please guide

Comment: `if ['DEF'] in rows(): print("Hello")`

Comment: `for i in rows():`. You need parenthesis to call the function, not brackets

Comment: got this error 
`TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rows = ( [u'ABC'], [u'DEF'], [u'GHI'])

print rows

for i in rows:
    print i
    if i == [u"DEF"]:
        print("Hello")
    if  i[0] == u"DEF":
        print "world"
```

I do not know, what exactly is your problem. 
The string is inside a list. Either you compare the complete list with a list of this string or the first element of the list with the string itself.